# What does updating JTable values actually do? Is there anyway I can get JTable values to create an object array which i can then write to file?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

```
JPanel classRegPanel = new JPanel(null); //layout

Object data[][]= new Object[10][5];  
String columns[]={"Name","ID","Present", "Absent", "Late"};  

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {

boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
            false, false, true, true,true
    };

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[columnIndex];
    }

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
{
return columnClass[columnIndex];
}};

JTable table=new JTable(model);  

JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);    

final Class[] columnClass = new Class[] 
{
String.class, Integer.class, Boolean.class, Boolean.class,Boolean.class
};


public void Setup()
{
this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    

this.add(scrollPane);

this.setTitle("Register");
this.setSize(500,380);
this.setVisible(true);
this.setResizable(false);
 }

public static void main(String[]   args )
{
  ClassRegister cr = new.   ClassRegister();
cr.Setup();
 }
```

Is there anyway I can write the updated JTable to an object array / string array?

The code is a simple version of a part of my program where I log the status of a student as present or absent. I then want to write this to file and figured I can do so by writing to an array then to file.

Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: The table model is what contains the values in your table. Read its javadoc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector--

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way i can do this?

1. You use the `getValueAt(...)` method to get the data for each cell in the table.
2. Then you write out each cell value to your file.